Matplotlib save format to keep zoomability
I'm calculating Mandelbrot sets and plotting them with matplotlib. I plot them with low quality for it to not take t0o much time processing. But I want to start to plot them with better quality and save them. I was wondering which format to use such that the graphs keep the best quality and zoom ability.
If it is impossible with matplotlib, is there an another python library that could work for what I want to do.
I don't know if it could help, but here is my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math
import time
timeatstart = time.time()
xmin = -1.6
xmax = 1.6
ymin = -1.6
ymax = 1.6
pixel_density = 1000
Iterations = 255
limit = 2
def zsquarec(z):
    return  z*z -0.75
def mandelbrot(z):
    z1 = z
    z2 = z
    curentIteration = 0
    for b in range(1, Iterations + 1):
        z2 = zsquarec(z1)
        z1 = z2
        if abs(z2) > limit:
            curentIteration = Iterations - b
            break
    return curentIteration
xDomaine = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,pixel_density)
yDomaine = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,pixel_density)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colorlist = []
for i in range(Iterations):
    colorlist.append([[],[]])
for x in xDomaine:
    for y in yDomaine:
        z3 = complex(x,y)
        color = mandelbrot(z3)
        colorlist[color][0].append(x)
        colorlist[color][1].append(y)
for clist in colorlist:
    if clist != [[],[]]:
        x = clist[0][0]
        y = clist[1][0]
        z = complex(x,y)
        color = mandelbrot(z)
        color = ((2*color % 256)/255, (240*color % 256)/255,(125*color % 256)/255)
        ax.scatter(clist[0],clist[1],c = color,s = 1)   
ax.set(xlim=(xmin,xmax),ylim=(ymin,ymax))
timeatend = time.time()
print(timeatend - timeatstart)
plt.show()

JPEG and PNG look horrible because their compression. And I don't know the other formats.

I usually use plt.savefig("Name.png", dpi = 660) for publications. Alternativerly if you want no compression at all, change .png to .tiff

Since you are computing the values at regular grid points you also could store them in an array and use imshow for plotting color values. This has the advantage that the image can be saved in a truly vectorized format (e.g. save as PDF -- no further dpi parameter needed) into which you can zoom in.
additionally, note that scatter produces circular marker which is why you see the following funny artifacts (overlapping discs) when you zoom in:

With imshow it looks like this

and also the file size drastically decreases.

plt.savefig('mandelbrot_plot.pdf', format='pdf')
plt.show()

This will save your plot in a vector format, allowing for high-quality zooming.

There is only one catch: if you're using scatter with round markers then the file size becomes rather large because circular markers are represented as polygons.
